# trying to program a timer so that a user can only input words for a certain amount of time

Tags: java, timer

I am trying to make a game where you can only enter words for 10 seconds. I tried to create a multithread solution but it doesn't work properly.

```
class timer extends Thread{//thread
public void run(){
    for(int i=10;i>=0;i--){
        System.out.print(i+" ");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Main method:

```
            timer t=new timer();
            t.start();
            while () {//not sure what to put in my while statement
                System.out.print("Guess a word on the board! ");
                if(test.CheckGame(scan.next())==true){
                    System.out.print("Good job! ");
                }
                else    
                    System.out.print("Guess again! ");
            }
```

essentially, after the thread goes for 10 seconds and terminates,I want it to return a break statement so the program leaves the while loop. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this

```
timer t=new timer();
t.start();
while (t.isAlive()) {//not sure what to put in my while statement
    System.out.print("Guess a word on the board! ");
    if(test.CheckGame(scan.next())==true){
        System.out.print("Good job! ");
    }
    else    
        System.out.print("Guess again! ");
}
```

Once the run function exits, t.isAlive will be false. You may also need to pass the timer object around and check the isAlive() of the object, depending on how CheckGame works. This is so that the input cannot be put in after the 10 seconds for an indefinite period of time.

Comment: the problem with this is that if the user is in the middle of the while loop then the loop won't terminate immediately

Comment: You may need to pass the timer object to your other methods and check it before the scan for input. Before you accept their input, you could also check the timer. How do your word check and input methods work?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple Demo that would let you to know how to use [`java.util.Timer` .](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Tester 
{
    static long i = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("You have only 10 seconds to find the result");
        System.out.println("What is the value of : 111111 X 111111 ");
        Timer timer = new Timer("Timer");
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                if (i == 12345654321L)
                {
                    System.out.println("Congrats!! you guessed the write answer :)");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Sorry Time is over. You couldn't guess the correct answer.");
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
        },10 * 1000 , 1);
        while (true)
        {
            i = scanner.nextLong(); 
            if ( i == 12345654321L)
            {
                System.out.println("Congrats!! you guessed the write answer :)");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Try next  guess :");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Since I don't have your all code so I am posting here the solution for your answer on my basic assumption. Don't use Thread. Instead use `java.util.Timer`. Your code would look as follows:

```
static String input=" ";//created a static variable input to take input 
public static void main(String st[])
{
    Timer timer = new Timer("Timer");
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            if (test.CheckGame(input))
            {
                System.out.println("Congrats!! you guessed the write answer :)");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry Time is over. You couldn't guess the correct answer.");
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
    },10 * 1000 , 1);//waits for 10 seconds
    while (true) 
    {
        System.out.print("Guess a word on the board! ");
        input = scan.next();
        if(test.CheckGame(input))
        {
            System.out.print("Good job! ");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Bad Guess. Try again ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a shared boolean where your thread and main share in a synchronized fashion.

The timer could be as follows;

```
class timer extends Thread{//thread
private Object lock = new Object(); // a lock used by both your thread and main to access stop boolean
private boolean stop = false;
public void setStop() // your thread calls this method in order to set stop
{
   synchronized(lock) {
   stop = true;
   }
}

public boolean getStop() // main calls this to see if thread told main to stop.
{
   boolean _stop;
   synchronized(lock) {
   _stop = stop;
   }
   return _stop;
}
public void run(){
    for(int i=10;i>=0;i--){
        System.out.print(i+" ");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setStop();
    }
}
}
```

Your main could be as follows:

```
timer t=new timer();
            t.start();
            while (!t.getStop()) {// calls getStop to see if other thread told main to stop
                System.out.print("Guess a word on the board! ");
                if(test.CheckGame(scan.next())==true){
                    System.out.print("Good job! ");
                }
                else    
                    System.out.print("Guess again! ");
            }
            t.join(); // to make sure main terminates after the termination of other thread
```

Comment: can you give me a code example of how to do that because I've only been learning multithreaded programming a few hours ago

Comment: Thank you! my only question is that if the person is in the middle of the while loop and the timer has run out, because you can only check if the timer has run out at the begining of the while loop, will this terminate the while loop even if the user is in the middle of typing?

Comment: i keep getting these errors when i try your code:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at timer.getStop(ultimateTest.java:18)
 at ultimateTest.main(ultimateTest.java:160)
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at timer.setStop(ultimateTest.java:10)
 at timer.run(ultimateTest.java:32)

Comment: @LouisB it is because I forgot to initialize `lock` in 
`private Object lock = new Object()`. Now it should run without exception.

Comment: my problem still remains, how to get the while loop to terminate one the time runs out when I am in the loop?