# Timed scanner in java

Tags: java, timer, java.util.scanner

Is it possible in Java to use a scanner and if no input was given in say 2 seconds, then it closes and the program decides what will happen? Like when you play snake, and it just continues to move if you don't press any buttons.

Comment: Sure, but I wouldn't use a scanner; better to do some key bindings.

Comment: You should really try to create an example first and ask for help if it doesn't work... this kind of questions are too general for the Q&A.

Comment: use currentTimeMillis() if tome exceed 2000 then do your code

Comment: If I am correct , all methods of java.util.Scanner will **lock/ freeze** your code execution **Till** input is entered , you some dynamic input system at the first place . Talking about timeouts . a background thread that will run every 2 seconds **endTask** , and if timer is X (say 2000 milliseconds) kill the program (exit) . so method to accept input **acceptInput** will *reset timer* and a method to  increment timer every 1 millisecond **incrementClock**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732362/trying-to-program-a-timer-so-that-a-user-can-only-input-words-for-a-certain-amou Follow the above link.

Answer (score 0):

I think  it could be done in more than one ways. 
But if you are talking about Snake game, it could be done with [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) and [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) classes. 
It will generate an ActionEvent after every certain time intervals.